# Copy / Paste popup options seem to inherit AlertDialog styles when EditText is placed within AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

When creating an AlertDialog (androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog) which contains and EditText (tried both EditText and AppCompatEditText), the copy and paste options popup which show when holding down on the text appear to inherit the style of the AlertDialog

This is the normal alert, working correctly
[image: The alert]

This is what happens when you open the copy/paste options

[image: With popup open]

(I have obfuscated what's behind the AlertDialog)

I'm setting the style of the AlertDialog in my activity theme

```
 <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/RoundedDialog</item>
...
...
 <style name="RoundedDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/alert_background</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

alert_background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid
    android:color="#FFF"/>
<corners
    android:radius="16dp" />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
```

And I am also removing the background after calling .show() on my builder to achieve rounded corners

```
this.window?.decorView?.background?.alpha = 0
```

Removing the alert_background appears to fix the problem, changing the decor view background has no effect.

As far as I can tell, the copy paste options box is inheriting the alert_background. How can i stop this from happening?